# Will deleting my SSH Key in Github now require me to enter my username and password?

Tags: git, github, token, ssh-keys

I've already created a personal Auth Token with Github but since I previously had a SSH key connected, I never had to enter my username or password when I would push my code to my repo. Will deleting the SSH Key in github now prompt me to enter my username and password? I want to confirm before deleting it and creating more confusion on for myself.

If I understand correctly, with Gits new requirements, I just need to use my personal Auth Token as my password in order to push my code.

Comment: The new "requirements" are to *NOT* use a username/password.  GitHub prefers Personal Auth Token, but also accepts an SSH key.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create new personal token in your github account at

Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal access token -> Generate Token

2.Updating Credentials Manager .

To open Credentials Manager search that setting or navigate to: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

In Generic Credentials find your repo and update username/password.Change password to Personal access token .